# Android Room @Embedded @Relation Class file location

Tags: android, android-room, android-mvvm, android-architecture

I had an argument with my co-worker about where we put `class` file that uses `@Embedded @Relation` annotations.
Do they count as Entities ? or should we create another package for them ? I have seen some `github` repo that they put them in `Entity` package and TBH usage of them look like entities to me .
We just don't want to mess the project architect duo to the complication and mass of the project also easy to read for other developers.

Comment: Something tells me that it would be difficult for you to get credible answer. Since it would be opinion-based. Somebody could have opinion that any class with any Room annotation should be placed in some isolated DBO package (as well as classes with Retrofit-annotations - in isolated DTO package). Since if you decide to replace Room with another framework, it wouldn't be clean enough to change any class outside some DBO scope. Someone would tell that package doesn't matter at all. It seems that most of the architecture-questions are opinion-based and couldn't be answered in unambiguous way

Comment: Well at least I tried. I just need to be convinced and need an answer that makes sense. Thank you for your comment

Comment: Personally I would put them in a separate package to other @Entity annotated classes. I'm not sure who I'm siding with here :)

Comment: Could you please explain why?